# What does NN VBD IN DT NNS RB means in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-parsing, pos-tagger

when I chunk text, I get lots of codes in the output like
`NN, VBD, IN, DT, NNS, RB`.
Is there a list documented somewhere which tells me the meaning of these? 
I have tried googling `nltk chunk code` `nltk chunk grammar` `nltk chunk tokens`.

But I am not able to find any documentation which explains what these codes mean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The tags that you see are not a result of the chunks but the POS tagging that happens before chunking. It's the Penn Treebank tagset, see https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> sent = "This is a Foo Bar sentence."
# POS tag.
>>> nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('Foo', 'NNP'), ('Bar', 'NNP'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
>>> tagged_sent = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
# Chunk.
>>> ne_chunk(tagged_sent)
Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Foo', 'NNP'), ('Bar', 'NNP')]), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')])
```

To get the chunks look for subtrees within the chunked outputs. From the above output, the `Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Foo', 'NNP'), ('Bar', 'NNP')])` indicates the chunk.

This tutorial site is pretty helpful to explain the chunking process in NLTK: [http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20150412115803/http://www.eecis.udel.edu:80/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf).

For official documentation, see http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html

Comment: Current links above are defunct. Try: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/part-of-speech-tagging.pdf

Comment: Try this https://web.archive.org/web/20150412115803/http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf

Answer (score 29):

Even though the above links have all kinds. But hope this is still helpful for someone, added a few that are missed on other links.

**CC**: Coordinating conjunction

**CD**: Cardinal number

**DT**: Determiner

**EX**: Existential there

**FW**: Foreign word

**IN**: Preposition or subordinating conjunction

**JJ**: Adjective

**VP**: Verb Phrase

**JJR**: Adjective, comparative

**JJS**: Adjective, superlative

**LS**: List item marker

**MD**: Modal

**NN**: Noun, singular or mass

**NNS**: Noun, plural

**PP**: Preposition Phrase

**NNP**: Proper noun, singular Phrase

**NNPS**: Proper noun, plural

**PDT**: Pre determiner

**POS**: Possessive ending

**PRP**: Personal pronoun Phrase

**PRP**: Possessive pronoun Phrase

**RB**: Adverb

**RBR**: Adverb, comparative

**RBS**: Adverb, superlative

**RP**: Particle

**S**: Simple declarative clause

**SBAR**: Clause introduced by a (possibly empty) subordinating conjunction

**SBARQ**: Direct question introduced by a wh-word or a wh-phrase.

**SINV**: Inverted declarative sentence, i.e. one in which the subject follows the tensed verb or modal.

**SQ**: Inverted yes/no question, or main clause of a wh-question, following the wh-phrase in SBARQ.

**SYM**: Symbol

**VBD**: Verb, past tense

**VBG**: Verb, gerund or present participle

**VBN**: Verb, past participle

**VBP**: Verb, non-3rd person singular present

**VBZ**: Verb, 3rd person singular present

**WDT**: Wh-determiner

**WP**: Wh-pronoun

**WP**: Possessive wh-pronoun

**WRB**: Wh-adverb

Comment: please let us know the source from where you this list with added tags ..

Comment: @shantanupathak It's a very old post; don't have a track to the links. Will have to search again.

Comment: Great resource with details here : [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/part-of-speech-tagging-nltk-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

As told by Alvas above, these tags are part-of-speech which tells whether a word/phrase is Noun phrase,Adverb,determiner,verb etc...

Here are the [POS Tag](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/02/penn-treebank-pos-tags-in-natural.html) details you can refer.

```
Chunking recovers the phrased from the Part of speech tags
```

You can refer this [link](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) for reading for about chunking.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has mentioned it, you can also add the line `nltk.help.upenn_tagset()` in your code, which will print out all the POS tags and their meaning!